# Apex CPU Limit Loading Large Data

Tags: apex, cpulimit

I am encountering and error while doing a data load.

here is my code when dataloading. is there anything that needs to be optimize in here so far?

```
public class depToAccount {
public static void deptpAccountV1(List<Dependent__c> depmem) {
    Set<Id> accountIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> coverIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id, List<Dependent__c>> atoDep = new Map<Id, List<Dependent__c>>();
    Map<Id, List<Dependent__c>> ctomeddep = new Map<Id, List<Dependent__c>>();
    Map<Id, List<Dependent__c>> cto19belowdep = new Map<Id, List<Dependent__c>>();
    Map<Id, List<Dependent__c>> ato19belowdep = new Map<Id, List<Dependent__c>>();
    Map<Id, List<Dependent__c>> cto20belowdep = new Map<Id, List<Dependent__c>>();
    Map<Id, List<Dependent__c>> ato20updep = new Map<Id, List<Dependent__c>>();//
    List<CampaignMember> cmList = new List<CampaignMember>();

    Map<Id, Account> accountToUpdateMap = new Map<Id, Account>();


    for(Dependent__c depm : depmem){
if(depm.status__c == 'ACTIVE' && depm.Catg__c == 'Vision'){
    accountIdSet.add(depm.Account__c);
    coverIdSet.add(depm.Cover__c); }
    }       
    accountIdSet.remove(null);
    coverIdSet.remove(null);

    List<Dependent__c> existingDependent = [SELECT Id, Account__c, Account__r.Name, Cover__c, Cover__r.Comply__c,Rel__c, status__c, Catg__c, Age_Today__c 
                                                        FROM Dependent__c 
                                                        WHERE ((Cover__c IN: coverIdSet AND Cover__c != null)
                                                               OR (Account__c IN: accountIdSet AND Account__c != null))
                                                        AND status__c ='ACTIVE' AND Plan_Name__c != NULL aND Catg__c != NULL];
    for(Dependent__c depM : existingDependent){
        if(depM.Age_Today__c < 19){
            {
                Depedendent__c[] records;
                if((records = cto19belowdep.get(depM.Cover__c)) == null) {
                    cto19Below.put(depM.Cover__c, records = new Dependent__c[0]);
                }
                records.add(depM);
            }

            if(ato19belowdep.containsKey(depM.Account__c)){
                ato19belowdep.get(depM.Account__c).add(depM);
            }
            else {
                ato19belowdep.put(depM.Account__c, new List<Dependent__c>{ depM });
            }
        }
        if(depM.Age_Today__c >= 19){
            {
                    Depedendent__c[] records;
                if((records = cto20belowdep.get(depM.Cover__c)) == null) {
                    cto20belowdep.put(depM.Cover__c, records = new Dependent__c[0]);
                }
                records.add(depM);
            }

            if(ato20updep.containsKey(depM.Account__c)){
                ato20updep.get(depM.Account__c).add(depM);
            }
            else {
                ato20updep.put(depM.Account__c, new List<Dependent__c>{ depM });
            }
        }
        if(depM.Catg__c == 'Vision'){
            if(ctomeddep.containsKey(depM.Cover__c)){
                ctomeddep.get(depM.Cover__c).add(depM);
            }
            else {
                ctomeddep.put(depM.Cover__c, new List<Dependent__c>{ depM });
            }
        }

        if(depM.Catg__c == 'Dental'){
            if(atoDep.containsKey(depM.Account__c)){
                atoDep.get(depM.Account__c).add(depM);
            }
            else {
                atoDep.put(depM.Account__c, new List<Dependent__c>{ depM });
            }
        }
    }
    Map<Id, Account> acctAttesAppMap = new Map<Id, Account>([Select ID,Good__c,Age_in_Numbers__pc,PersonContactId,Phone__c ,NumberofYears__c  FROM Account where ID IN : accountIdSet ]);

    for(Id acctId : accountIdSet){
    Account accRecord = accRecord);
        for(Dependent__c depM : existingDependent){
            for(Id covId : coverIdSet){
                if(cto19belowdep.containsKey(covId) && depM.Cover__c==covId){ 
                    for(Dependent__c depU19 : cto19belowdep.get(covId)){
                        if(depU19.Age_Today__c < 19){ 

                            if((atoDep.containsKey(acctId)) || (accRecord.Good__c == true) || accRecord.NumberofYears__c > 0 )){ 
                                if(ctomeddep.containsKey(covId)){
                                    for(Dependent__c depMemMedi : ctomeddep.get(covId)){ 
                                        accountToUpdateMap.put(depMemMedi.Account__c, new Account(Id=depMemMedi.Account__c, Compliant__c=true, Comply__c=false));
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                            else {
                                if((!atoDep.containsKey(acctId)) || (accRecord.Good__c == false) || (accRecord ).NumberofYears__c == 0 )){ 
                                    if(ctomeddep.containsKey(covId)){
                                        for(Dependent__c depMemMedi : ctomeddep.get(covId)){
                                            accountToUpdateMap.put(depMemMedi.Account__c, new Account(Id=depMemMedi.Account__c, Compliant__c=false, Comply__c=false));
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                                IF(accRecord.Phone__c != NULL ){
                                    {

                                        cmList.add( new CampaignMember(
                                            CampaignId  = System.Label.Doctor_Campaign,
                                            ContactId = accRecord).PersonContactId,
                                            Status = 'Completed'
                                        ));


                                    }
                                }
                                IF(accRecord.Phone__c == NULL && accRecord.Age_in_Numbers__pc >= 19){
                                    {
                                        cmList.add( new CampaignMember(
                                            CampaignId  = System.Label.Nurse_Campaign,
                                            ContactId = accRecord).PersonContactId,
                                            Status = 'Completed'
                                        ));
                                    }
                                }
                                IF(accRecord.Phone__c == NULL &&  accRecord.Age_in_Numbers__pc < 19){
                                    {
                                        cmList.add( new CampaignMember(
                                            CampaignId  = System.Label.Staff_Campaign,
                                            ContactId = accRecord).PersonContactId,
                                            Status = 'Completed'
                                        ));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                else if(cto20belowdep.containsKey(covId) && depM.Cover__c==covId){
                    for(Dependent__c depU20 : cto20belowdep.get(covId)){
                        if(depU20.Age_Today__c >= 19){ 
                            if(atoDep.containsKey(acctId) ){
                                if(ctomeddep.containsKey(covId)){
                                    for(Dependent__c depMemMedi : ctomeddep.get(covId)){
                                        accountToUpdateMap.put(depMemMedi.Account__c, new Account(Id=depMemMedi.Account__c, Compliant__c=false, Comply__c=true));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                if(depM.Cover__r.Comply__c==true && depM.Cover__c == covId){
                    if(ctomeddep.containsKey(covId)) 
                        for(Dependent__c CMmed : ctomeddep.get(covId)){
                            accountToUpdateMap.put(CMmed.Account__c, new Account(Id=CMmed.Account__c, Compliant__c=false, Comply__c=true));
                        }
                } 

            }
        }
    }
    database.insert(cmlist, false);
    update accountToUpdateMap.values();

}
```

}

Comment: How is this code being run? Is it called from a trigger, run in Anonymous Apex, ...? How many records is the main query returning?

Comment: Going to take a moment, there's a lot you can optimize here.

Comment: this is run using an update trigger  depToAccount.depToAccountV1(trigger.new); it is a job that loads around 1.2M data.

Comment: I am planning to limit it by 10000, but my queston would be if I Limit that to 10k, will the whole record run? or only 10k?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(Dependent__c depm : depmem){
    if(depm.status__c == 'ACTIVE' && depm.Catg__c == 'Vision'){
        if(depm.Account__c != null){
            accountIdSet.add(depm.Account__c);
        }
        if(depm.Cover__c != null){
            coverIdSet.add(depm.Cover__c); 
        }
    }
}
```

You don't need to check for null here. You can do it at the end:

```
for(Dependent__c depm : depmem){
    if(depm.status__c == 'ACTIVE' && depm.Catg__c == 'Vision'){
        accountIdSet.add(depm.Account__c);
        coverIdSet.add(depm.Cover__c); 
    }
}
accountIdSet.remove(null);
coverIdSet.remove(null);
```

Probably doesn't matter, but you can optimize the query, too. Also, you're only looking for records where cover *and* account matches, which will return far fewer records:

```
List<Dependent__c> existingDependent = [SELECT Id, Account__c, Account__r.Name, Cover__c, Cover__r.Comply__c,Rel__c, status__c, Catg__c, Age_Today__c 
                                                    FROM Dependent__c 
                                                    WHERE ((Cover__c IN: coverIdSet)
                                                        AND (Account__c IN: accountIdSet))
                                                    AND status__c ='ACTIVE' AND Plan_Name__c != NULL aND Catg__c != NULL];
```

Instead of checking for a key then calling get, you can do both at once to improve efficiency:

```
{
    Depedendent__c[] records;
    if((records = cto19belowdep.get(depM.Cover__c)) == null) {
        cto19Belowmap.put(depM.Cover__c, records = new Dependent__c[0]);
    }
    records.add(depM);
}
```

Get objects from a map as few times as possible; cache the data for performance:

```
if((atoDep.containsKey(acctId)) || (acctAttesAppMap.get(acctId).Good__c == true) || (acctAttesAppMap.get(acctId ).NumberofYears__c > 0 )){
```

...

```
if((!atoDep.containsKey(acctId)) || (acctAttesAppMap.get(acctId).Good__c == false) || (acctAttesAppMap.get(acctId ).NumberofYears__c == 0 )){
```

...

Can be rewritten as:

```
Account accRecord = acctAttesAppMap.get(acctId);
```

...

```
if((atoDep.containsKey(acctId)) || (accRecord.Good__c == true) || (accRecord.NumberofYears__c > 0 )){
```

...

```
if((!atoDep.containsKey(acctId)) || (accRecord.Good__c == false) || (accRecord.NumberofYears__c == 0 )) {
```

...

Finally, this loop can be optimized:

```
for(Id acctId : accountIdSet){
    for(Dependent__c depM : existingDependent){
        for(Id covId : coverIdSet){
```

You'll need to use maps to achieve this.

Comment: I have replaced the if(cto19belowdep.containsKey(depM.Cover__c)){
                cto19belowdep.get(depM.Cover__c).add(depM);
            }
            else {
                cto19belowdep.put(depM.Cover__c, new List<Dependent__c>{ depM });
            } with {
    Depedendent__c[] records;
    if((records = cto19belowdep.get(depM.Cover__c) == null) {
        cto19Belowmap.put(depM.Cover__c, records = new Dependent__c[0]);
    }
    records.add(depM);
} it seems the error was Compile Error: Illegal assignment from Boolean to List<Dependent__c>

Comment: @Cloud There was a missing parentheses in the code. Try the new version.

Comment: do I need to get the account as well? like these?Depedendent__c[] records;
    if((records = cto19belowdep.get(depM.Cover__c)) == null) {
        cto19Belowmap.put(depM.Cover__c, records = new Dependent__c[0]);
    }
    records.add(depM);
 
 Account__c[] accountrecords;
 if((accountrecords = ato19belowdep.get(depM.Account__c)) == null) {
        ato19belowdep.put(depM.Account__c, accountrecords = new Dependent__c[0]);
    }
    records.add(depM);

Comment: I have editted do you think that would help now loading millions of data? thank you

Comment: @Cloud You still have other places you can optimize your map usage. You also apparently missed the bit about updating your filters. You should be able to reduce the number of records returned by using AND instead of OR. Also, I wasn't quite sure how to write the last set of loops, but those can clearly use a map or two to reduce the matching process to linear time instead of exponential time. You might also ultimately just need to reduce the data load batch size in order to keep the process running fast enough to avoid limits.

Comment: sorry got confused in here, {
                Depedendent__c[] records;
                if((records = cto19belowdep.get(depM.Cover__c)) == null) {
                    cto19Below.put(depM.Cover__c, records = new Dependent__c[0]);
                }
                records.add(depM);
            }

            if(ato19belowdep.containsKey(depM.Account__c)){
                ato19belowdep.get(depM.Account__c).add(depM);
            }
            else {
                ato19belowdep.put(depM.Account__c, new List<Dependent__c>{ depM });
            } shall i do this to the account as wel

Comment: @Cloud Yes, you can. It's a decent optimization.

Comment: but will this get the first record? or only the 2nd and the succeeding record? so in this case it would be like these? { Depedendent__c[] records; if((records = cto19belowdep.get(depM.Cover__c)) == null) { cto19Below.put(depM.Cover__c, records = new Dependent__c[0]); } if((records = ato19belowdep.get(depM.Account__c)) == null) { ato19belowdep.put(depM.Account__c, records = new Dependent__c[0]); } records.add(depM); }

Comment: hi sfdcfox, I am still having issues, and apex still occuring, how do I move that to map? thank you

Comment: do you have sample on how can I convert that into a map?

Comment: @Cloud I didn't really understand what the purpose of your code is (it's far too long to be comfortable to read, you might want to use functions to break it up). Consider asking a new question that contains the code your stuck on, the context around it, anything you've attempted so far, and what the code is supposed to do. From there, it'll be easier for us to assist you.

Comment: it seems that I am stuck in here. for(Id acctId : accountIdSet){
    for(Dependent__c depM : existingDependent){
        for(Id covId : coverIdSet){ and as i do a dataload it is hitting on these